# Spring Boot 1.5.6 doesn't find index.html

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to connect index.html to my spring boot app to make localhost:8080 return it.

I have already tried various ways and I always get 404.
Here is the part of my application.properties

```
server.context-path=/
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**
spring.resources.add-mappings=true
```

index.html is in src/main/resources/static directory. Can usage of Apache CXF for REST API somehow affect it?

Comment: can you post your controller ?

Comment: Remove `spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**` from your properties.

Comment: @georgesvan I don't have a mvc controller

Comment: It doesn't help @JBNizet

Comment: If you did what @JBNizet said, your index.html should be accessible via `locahost:8080/index.html`. With your original configuration it should be accessible via `localhost:8080/resources/index.html`.

Comment: @DanielJayMarcaida still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

- Delete this properties, you don't need them.
- make sure you don't have `@EnableWebMvc` annotation anywhere.
- if you run your application from jar, you should have configured spring-boot-maven-plugin in your pom.
- if you run your application from IDE, try to rebuild your project.

  It is hard to tell what can be wrong. If nothing helps, you should start a new project from: https://start.spring.io/
  and if it also will not work, then we should look for the problem somewhere else.